# Retrofit 2 with coroutine call adapter factory cancel request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, deferred, kotlinx.coroutines

I am trying to implement dynamic search functionality in my android application using retrofit2 with coroutine call adapter factory. When user type keyword and if keyword length is valid then app make request to server. In single request i can request like below

```
launch(UI) {
        try {
            val user = Client.provideService().getUsers()
            //do sometihng with user.await()
        }catch (e: Exception){
            //Handle exception
        }
    }
```

but what if i want to cancel every previous request and make new request when user changes the editable ? I search a lot for an example but i cant find anything useful. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to cancel a coroutine, you can do that as explained in this [guide](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#cancelling-coroutine-execution). You need to invoke `cancel` on the `Job` that is returned from `launch`:

```
val job = launch {
   //...
}

job.cancel() // cancels the job
```

But it's very important to know that *Coroutine cancellation is cooperative*, i.e. the block executed in the coroutine needs to react on the cancellation from outside the coroutine. You can check the state with `isActive` as described [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#making-computation-code-cancellable).

As for your example, you would have to be able to cancel the computation of `Client.provideService().getUsers()` as soon as `isActive` becomes `true`.

Comment: Explicitly checking `isActive` is necessary only for loops that almost never get suspended. In OP's case, the coroutine will be suspended until the response comes in, and if it's canceled in that state, it won't resume.

Comment: This is not working. Deferred<>.cancel  not working after await called. I need an another good design.

Comment: What do you mean by "after"? You can't expect to cancel a call from the same coroutine where you called `await`, that's a contradiction.

Comment: In viewMode class there is a field, val data = MutableLiveData<User>() When response returns we set new user to data. Assume that user requested with keyword "jo" then response return and viewmodel set the data value. But user keep typing and make the keyword "joh" then if viewmodel dont cancel previous request data will be wrong because of "jo" requests response. In retrofit2 with call or rxjava2 with disposable we can make call.cancel or disposable.dispose and request again with new keyword. How can we handle this case with coroutines. I hope i am clear enough.